# Comparing the NSString dates keys in an NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibaction

I was wondering how would I express the non-matching dates values in Xcode, for example I have this two buttons one to present today's events and the other to present future events, I managed to code the first button which is loading today's events, But i don't know how to do it for future events like how to say "if the date of the event does not match the date on the calendar, then load these events"??

Below, is some of my code for my todaysEvents button,

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *dateEvents;
 @end


 @implementation HomeViewController {
      NSArray *_events;
      NSArray *_dateEvents;
      NSMutableArray *displayedEvents;
 }



- (IBAction)todaysEvents:(id)sender {

     [_pendingOperations.downloadQueue cancelAllOperations];

     [displayedEvents removeAllObjects];

     NSDate *currDate = [NSDate date];
     NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
     [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-YYYY"];
     NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currDate];


     [displayedEvents addObjectsFromArray:[_events filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate 
                       predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(Events * event, NSDictionary *bindings)
                       {
                            NSLog(@"%@ ?= %@", event.date , dateString);
                           return [event.date isEqualToString:dateString];
                       }]]];

     NSLog(@"%@", displayedEvents);

     [self.myTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: whats wrong with your code?

Comment: You question is unclear. Can you provide more details about what your problem is, or perhaps a screenshot of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @lead_the_zeppelin there is nothing wrong with the above code, I just want to write something similar to it for the future events but I don't know how to present the case where the date of the event is not matching the current calendar date in order to load the future events ..

Comment: @JamesFrost I just want to write something similar to the above code for the future events button but I don't know how to present the case where the date of the event is not matching the current calendar date in order to load the future events ..

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to simply compare strings, then use the following code:

```
if([string1 isEqualToString:string2])
{
     //The strings are equal, do something here
}
```

**UPDATE**: Since you are trying to check for 2 strings that are ***not*** equal, simply add the not operator(!). Like so:

```
 if(![string1 isEqualToString:string2])
{
     //The strings are equal, do something here
}
```

Comment: I don't want to simplify, Im just asking about how to express the case where the value of string one which is a date is not equal to the value of string two which is also a date !!

Comment: Thats exactly what this code does, instead of string1 and string2 change them to the names of your variables for your dates.

Answer (score 0):

You've created a predicate that matches today's date. You're using a date formatter to generate a date string with month day and year, and then matching the date string of toaday's date to a date string from your _events array, which isn't a very flexible way of doing it, but it works.

If now you only want to select dates other than today, simply change your predate to read:

```
[displayedEvents addObjectsFromArray:[_events filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(Events * event, NSDictionary *bindings)
{
  NSLog(@"%@ ?= %@", event.date , dateString);
  return ![event.date isEqualToString:dateString];
}
```

(I just added a "!" to the return statement to match all dates EXCEPT today.)

If instead you want to match all dates AFTER today (future dates, as you suggest in your text) then you'll need to change your method of matching dates. You'll want to use NSCalendar and probably the method `components:fromDate:toDate:options:` with a components value of NSDayCalendarUnit, and options of 0 (do not wrap). That will let you calculate the number of days difference between the current date and a date from your array. You could use that to create a predicate that only selects dates that are at least 1 day greater than the current date.

That should be enough for you to solve your problem.

Comment: so are u saying I have to change my method for matching dates for todays events as well or only for future events ?? because the thing is I have declared the EventDate as NSString and if Im going to do your way then i have to convert my eventDate into NSDate or I could change the matching method for todays UIButton !!

Comment: From your code it looks like your dates are stored internally as NSDates. That's good. If you want to do range calculations (e.g. all dates later than today) then yes, you will need to change your code to not use strings but use the approach I outlined to figure out the number of days difference between NSDates.

Comment: okay I got that, but do I still going to use my above predicate functions as it is ?? and there is something I don't know it .. how to write the function for the predicate that selects dates 1 day greater than the current date ?

Comment: Ok, so go read up on NSCalendar, NSDateComponents, and the method components:fromDate:toDate:options:

Comment: yeah Im trying to get them, but u have not answered my question can I still use my above predicate function with components:fromDate:toDate:options: ?